# Datatables find string and add class

Tags: datatables, find, addclass

I try to find string in my table and add class to this row. But this code doesn't work. Just nothing happens. Here is my code, latter I call `myTable()` function:

```js
function myTable() {
    var selectDateVar = $('#selectDate').val();

        var table = $('#example').DataTable( { // Таблица
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "bDestroy": true,

            "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php?data=30/09/2015",
            "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
            initComplete: function(){
                var api = this.api();

                new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(api, {
                    buttons: [
                        {
                        extend: 'print',
                        text: 'Принтиране',
                        'className': 'btn-lg btn btn-warning printBTN',
                        },
                    ]
                });

                api.buttons().container().appendTo( '.printButton' );  
            }

        });

        var indexes = table.rows().eq( 0 ).filter( function (rowIdx) {
            return table.cell( rowIdx, 3 ).data() === '180' ? true : false;
        } );
        table.rows( indexes ).nodes().to$().addClass( 'highlight' );
    }
```

My table:

[image]

I use this example https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

Comment: @Spirit yes, I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function myTable() {
    var selectDateVar = $('#selectDate').val();

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( { // Таблица
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "bDestroy": true,

        "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php?data=30/09/2015",
        "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
        initComplete: function(){
            var api = this.api();
            new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(api, {
                buttons: [
                    {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'Принтиране',
                    'className': 'btn-lg btn btn-warning printBTN',
                    },
                ]
            });

            api.buttons().container().appendTo( '.printButton' );  

            //filtering code should be inside of initComplete function
            //but in your case an empty table is filtered
            var indexes = table.rows().eq( 0 ).filter( function (rowIdx) {
                 return table.cell( rowIdx, 3 ).data() === '180' ? true : false;
            } );

            table.rows( indexes ).nodes().to$().addClass( 'highlight' );
        }

    });
}
```

You need to call the code on data load. Currently you call it before the table is filled with server data. Just add your code sample to initComplete function. 
initComplete will be called after the moment Ajax data is loaded.

**The answer to the second question:** if you need to search across several columns just add the following code:

```js
var indexes = table.rows().eq( 0 ).filter( function (rowIdx) {
    return table.cell( rowIdx, 3 ).data() === '180' &&
           table.cell( rowIdx, 0 ).data() === '521' ? true : false;
} );
```

Comment: yes work like a charm, but if I use search, pagination, sort, refresh table the class just gone. Is there some fix for that?

Comment: @diank - you could execute the code in [**drawCallback**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) so the class is added each time the table is redrawn.